# Jaya evolution to Bharat and then to Mahabharat

Tags: mahabharata, indology

Indologist Koenraad Elst mentions that first there was Jaya (original Mahabharat) written by Vyasa, then it expanded into Mahabharat. Here's the video where he says so https://youtu.be/myBXPSYIiTY?t=1239

He also says Mahabharat also mentions this. Could anyone cite the verses which say certify this evolution of Mahabharat?

Please prefer to mention BORI verses if possible as its easy to find and I have copy of it.

Comment: @YDS No, these verses speak of Jaya which is just a set of 8800 which are maybe hard to understand. Nowhere does it speak of an evolution of Jaya into Mahabharat.